# nginx cakephp virtual host redirects

Tags: php, cakephp, nginx

I'm new to nginx and can't get my site to work (a Cakephp site  on AWS).  I'm getting the messsage "The page isn't redirecting properly" and some how something is appending the domain to itself (a redirect loop);

example when i enter my site `sub1.mysite.com` the browers adds `sub1.mysite.com/sub1.mysite.com/sub1.mysite.com/sub1.mysite.com` and so on.

Here's my sites-available config

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name sub1.mysite.com;
   rewrite ^(.*) http://sub1.mysite.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
  server_name name sub1.mysite.com;
  root /var/www/sub1.mysite.com/public_html/sub-root;
  index  index.php index.html index.htm;

  # error_page 404 errors/404.html;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/sub1.mysite.com.access.log;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }
    location ~ .php$ {
        root /var/www/sub1.mysite.com/public_html/sub-root;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with your first nginx server directive:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name sub1.mysite.com;
   rewrite ^(.*) http://sub1.mysite.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Your directive is listening on port 80 (http) and responds to `sub1.mysite.com` then it matches everything `^(.*)` and redirects to `http://sub1.mysite.com$1 permanent` where the `$1` is the result of your matching so basically, it appends `sub1.mysite.com`. I don't see any reason why you need this server directive? it listens to the same port as your main server directive and responds to the same `server_name` Just delete it. The result should be (note I fixed some settings, look at the notes for more details):

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    server_name sub1.mysite.com; # removed the redundant 'name' keyword that you used here
    root /var/www/sub1.mysite.com/public_html/sub-root;

    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    charset utf-8; # added this, you don't have to.

    # error_page 404 errors/404.html;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sub1.mysite.com.access.log;

    # edited this. Given the request to `sub1.mysite.com` it will
    # try to first match the file itself, than an index file in the root
    # directory and then it will just send the request to index.php with the query string
    # which means the request to sub1.mysite.com/dashboard will be forwarded
    # to sub1.mysite.com/index.php/dashboard
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # added both of these lines, you don't have to. they are just good practice.
    # If you don't add them your log files will get bloated real fast.
    # these files are requested by crawlers.
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ \.php$ { # added a '\'
        # removed redundant 2 lines here
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

If you had another mean in your mind for the first server directive, let me know.

Comment: Where were you 2 days ago...just kidding :-). Seriously, thank you so much. Its working!! Although, the only issue I'm having now is `index.php`.If I click on any of the 'pretty urls' on the nav it works;ex: if I click on "dashboard" which is `sub1.mysite.com\dashboard`, it forwards fine. If I go to the index directly it works fine `sub1.mysite.com/index.php`.  But if go to the site & not specify index file (sub1.mysite.com) I get error **"Missing Controller Error: Sub1.mysite.comController could not be found."**.  Looks like its passing the domain name to cake's controller.Any idea?

Comment: @user20719 check my edited answer. The error you are getting is CakePHP error? I've never used CakePHP. Anyways, if it is a CakePHP error then it means that your nginx configurations are probably OK but there is an issue with your route declaration. Take a look at your router